# My laptop sleeps unexpectedly while working

Tags: laptop, drivers, hardware-failure, sleep, acpi

My DELL Inspiron 15 3000 Series 3567
It sleeps while working on it due to palm rest pressure or some jerk.

I have disabled sleep from settings that What closing the lid does but the problem is still there but now it flicks for 2 seconds and revives back to normal.

I could not find any solution to it over Internet.

But i found something about Sleep Sensors in laptop under the palm rest still I'm clue less.

Please give me some insight into it.

I checked my driver

Also my Optical Drive is not Ejecting(just telling for information this one is old issue but maybe some relation)

Then I checked devmgmt.msc (Device Manager) there clicked Hidden Drivers and then saw something acpi processor aggregator hidden. Maybe it was hidden forever I don't know.

Comment: "some jerk"? Please explain. Your computer has a hardware fault if physical actions cause it to sleep. You'll need to oursue warranty repair or hardware service.

Comment: its out of warranty  3years ago

Comment: please tell me one thing can a dirty laptop fan cause such issue? like cpu not cooling properly and making pc sleep (yes it sleeps instead of shut down)

Comment: It can, or it cannot. It depends and we cannot answer this unless we have the computer in our physical possession and can inspect it ourselves. It also has nothing to do with the other symptoms you have described.