# My Laptop randomly goes to sleep while working maybe because of malfucntioning lid sensor. How to solve it?

Tags: windows, laptop

My laptop sleeps randomly sometimes while working on it. I observed it is due to pressure of my palm over the palm rest.

I've googled about that and found about lid sensor are involved in sleep mechanism when we close lid and now i am sure it's due to the same sensor(faulty) that this problem is happening.

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 15 3000 Series 3567 I am unable to find about my Lid Sensor in book manual of the Laptop.

Can anyone help me how to disable that switch entirely or where is the location of that switch.

I've disabled the setting of sleep on closing lid. But that seem not to help me much. Problem occurance frequency has reduced but problem is still there. Now it takes less time like moments of second to turn back on from sleep unlike earlier.

PS: I dont have virus on my pc so rule that possibility out.

Comment: Could you use an external keyboard for a while, to be sure it is due to the palm rest?  Apart from that: https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/How-i-fixed-blank-screen-lid-closer-sensor-reed-switch-problem/td-p/3103660

Comment: Yes I can and when I squeeze the edge of my palm rest or gently twist it the laptop comes out of sleep again

Comment: So I'm sure its something beneath the palm rest

Comment: But the sensor seems to be magnetic.  Pressure shouldn't trigger it.  Of course it wouldn't hurt to have a look.  Is your system out of warranty?

Comment: I'm afraid If i cut it then it might sleep forever :(

Comment: Yes out of warranty

Comment: Is there possibility of HDD SATA port loose? I never got any such prompt like never got errors like HDD is loose or not found

Comment: No fear, it's a trigger.  But I would try not to do anything irreversible.  Prefer to remove it using a soldering iron if the surroundings allow you to do that.

Comment: What's this about a HDD?

Comment: I found on internet that loose HDD can cause sleep too so i was worried since its beneath palm rest too i guess isnt it?

Comment: I'm sorry, my laptop is an MSI.

Comment: and orientation is also one of preference to my sleeping laptop when i turn it 90 degrees (screen flat on table) it wakes up and then i turn it in some other orientation the sleep is induced sometimes this might be coincidence as well dont take this one comment so seriously

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My laptop sleeps unexpectedly while working](https://superuser.com/questions/1569617/my-laptop-sleeps-unexpectedly-while-working)

Comment: Thats same question asked by me.

Answer (score 0):

I Have had this issue with my Dell laptop for the last year, i have just discovered that there is a magnet in the top righthand side of the screen with operates a switch on the bottom righthand side of the laptop to put it in to sleep mode. I wear a magnetic bracelet on  my right wrist and its this that is operateing the switch and putting the laptop to sleep :) aaaaaaaaahhhhhhhh

Comment: I don't wear anything on my wrist.

Comment: Is there possibility of pinching of wire at hinge of screen and body